# Why this error happens with groovy sql jdbc builder?

Tags: sql, groovy

Why this code does not get the string for sql.execute("$y")?

```
    import groovy.sql.Sql
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root","password", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    def y= "select * from table"
    table(sql,y)
    def table(sql,x){
        println ("$x")
        sql.execute("$x")
    }
```

The Output:

```
'select * from table'
Sep 02, 2017 3:49:39 PM groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: ? because: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from table'' at line 1
Caught: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from table'' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from table'' at line 1
```

Comment: "double" apostrophes have macrosubstitition in groovy, 'single' not

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved word... Needs to be delimited. (MySQL uses back-ticks.) But, even better, rename the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql.execute("$x")
```

in groovy double-quoted string with `$expression` inside is actually a [groovy.lang.GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html)

so you are calling this method: [Sql.execute(Gstring query)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute-groovy.lang.GString-)

this method replaces all `$expressions` in groovy string with `?`

creates prepared statement and pass all `$expressions` as parameters of this prepared  statement

in your case `"$x"` converted to `"?"` and executed.

Mysql tries to parse this query `"?"` and gives you an error:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

if you change your code to this:

```
sql.execute("$x" as String)
```

You'll beat this problem but you will face another one: you can't select rows with method `Sql.execute(...)`

**examples with parameters**

The following commands are equivalent:

```
def rows = sql.rows("select * from mytable where fieldA = $value")

def rows = sql.rows("select * from mytable where fieldA = ?", [value] )

def parms = [VALUE: value]
def rows = sql.rows(parms, "select * from mytable where fieldA = :VALUE")
```

all of them will be executed as a prepared statement `"select * from mytable where fieldA = ?"`

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Again I am getting same error.

Comment: But I explained why... did you made any changes to code?

Comment: Thanks for your response bro. you are exactly correct. Now only i realise where i did mistake. your answers helped me very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by the method shown below.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root","password", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def y= "select * from tablename"
table(sql,y)
def table(sql,x){
    println (x)
    sql.execute(x)
}
```

`"select * from table"` query can't work. Because `table` is a keyword in `sql`.

This simple change works without any errors. Thanks for your responses.